# Retina images-picturefill.js and media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, retina-display

When accommodating retina displays by creating a second image twice as large I've seen picturefill.js recommended to prevent download of the larger images unless they are needed.

But isn't this what the  'min-device-pixel-ratio' media query already accomplishes?
Or is it that images in your CSS are ALWAYS downloaded even if the particular query isn't met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the images only get downloaded if it meets the correct CSS criteria. So you are safe to use media queries over picturefill.js. Have a look at this article, which does tests on image requests based on media queries: http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/. Similarly, you can also use Chrome Dev Tools Network tab to see the images that are requested on load - you'll find only the images in the media queries that are met will be downloaded.